# How to identify all the html files in current directory

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have below piece of code which has report.html and identified using below lines

```
  build.getWorkspace().child("report_${BUILD_NUMBER}/report.html")
```

There are few more html files called report1.html, and report2.html as per the above line I can able to parse only report.html but I just want to identify all the html file which is start with "report".

Any inputs...

Comment: Did you try something like : `Build.getWorkspace().child("report_${BUILD_NUMBER}/report*.html")`

Answer (score 0):

`build.getWorkspace()` returns `hudson.FilePath` object, so you can check all the methods in documentation

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html

this should work:

```
build.getWorkspace().list("report_${BUILD_NUMBER}/report*.html")
```

Comment: Observed exception : java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /testJob-9571/workspace//target/surefire-reports/emailable-report*.html